# Ssrs Report Scheduling

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report in SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services (SSRS) that I'd like to schedule to run automatically for the previous dates (That Means this a Banking Related Report and the Transaction date is Today's Date ) I would like the Report to generate daily automatically for Yesteraday's date  i.e. suppose Transaction date is `15-01-2012` I want to send yesterday s transaction date  i.e. `14-01-2013` report daily to the customer.

Is it posible and how can I do this please explain.

Answer (score 3):

Few steps here:

1. Set up the report to work with a default date parameter, and set the default expression to yesterday, e.g. `=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Today())`.
2. Set the report to retrieve its Dataset based on the parameter.
3. Schedule the report through Report Manager and set the date parameter to use its default value, i.e. yesterday:

[image: Default parameter]

If you've never done it before, creating a subscription in Report Manager:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189680.aspx

Comment: Glad it's going now - please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer if you're happy with it.